# How do I solve this Combobox Glitch?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created my own combobox with minor changes. But I am facing bug in dropdownlist.
I've Set `combobox.DroppedDown = True` in the form
 
This happens in every form everytime when I open a new form.
 
The Combobox code is

```
Public Class MainComboxex

Inherits ComboBox

Private Sub MainComboBoxEx_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Enter
    Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(247, 180, 65)
End Sub

Private Sub MainComboBoxEx_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Leave
    Me.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub

'Private Sub InitializeComponent()
'    Me.SuspendLayout()
'    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
'End Sub

Private Sub MainComboxex_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    Try
        If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
            e.Handled = AutoFillCombo(Me, e.KeyChar.ToString)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

But It behaves like this..[image: Error Pic]

After Again Clicking on the combobox, it works proper as shown below.
[image: working PIC]

Comment: *I've Set combobox.DroppedDown = True in the form*. Where? Are you using some sort of `AutoCompleteCustomSource` that takes time to fill? You have a Custom ComboBox, but it's not clear whether those event handlers are set in the Form or the Custom Control. If the latter, you should override `OnEnter`, `OnLeave` etc, not subscribe to the event.

Comment: @Jimi Nope, no source. Combobox items written by default in items collection.

Comment: Well, what is `AutoFillCombo()` doing then? You understand that if I create a class using this code, the problem doesn't reproduce. Do you have something else in `Form.Load()` that can get in the way, something related to this ComboBox (its location, parenting or anything else)?

Comment: @Jimi AutoFillCombo() is like if I write 'A' in combobox text then it'll complete other word from its itemlist i.e 'CCOUNT MASTER'. Again if I write C then it'll autocomplete 'COUNT MASTER'. If I write 'P' then it'll complete 'RODUCT MASTER'